GeoLocation classification
I am working on location tracking software,I am getting coordinates from mobile and I am storing the Coordinates in sql db.I have certain pre-defined places around which I have created Geofence with radius around those places coordinates.Now,I am classifying the point as  Geofence point or Extra location point.Now I need to track if user stops at certain place outside of geofence for more than 5 minutes.
Since I am storing location coordinates in DB,I tried grouping based on address ,(so here address means for location data outside geofence ,I am finding out address and storing it in DB as a field).I am calculating time difference after grouping like start_time as min(createdat) and end_time as max(createdat).I am checking time difference and if its greater than 5 minutes,I am storing it as extra location,Now the problem arises when I revisit any address again,the end_time will change,which will result in increased time difference,It is calclating as stoppage time,Is there a way to track count or   distinguish the revisit ?
